# Error when trying to use Parse in watchOS2 App

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, watchos-2

I have tried to add Parse using cocoa pods to a watchOS2 App here is the pod file

```
target 'OS2Test WatchKit Extension' do
    pod 'Parse',                    '~> 1.8.2'
end
```

When I compile I get the following error:

```
In file included from ~/Xcode_Projects/OS2Test/OS2Test WatchKit Extension/InterfaceController.m:10:
In file included from ~/Xcode_Projects/OS2Test/Pods/Headers/Public/Parse/Parse.h:36:
~/Xcode_Projects/OS2Test/Pods/Headers/Public/Parse/PFPurchase.h:11:9: fatal error: 'StoreKit/StoreKit.h' file not found
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>
        ^
1 error generated.
```

It seems that StoreKit framework can not be added to the app, so is there  is a parse version that supports watchOS2?? or what?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the StoreKit.h file exists in your Pods project? Normally what I do is make a pod install and just import the header file I want to use without having to import the class first. Just try after the pod install:

```
#import "Storekit.h"
```

Comment: `StoreKit` is an iOS framework and it seems that it is not supported on Watch, the problem is that Parse pod uses it that is why I got this error

Comment: Try adding `@import StoreKit;` then, that will add the StoreKit class to your project. Sorry, I still have to get my hands on the WatchOS kit but I added that to one of my projects and it built without issues.

Comment: `StoreKit` is not available for native watch app, @import will not work